# Local Service not calling .exe under different user account

Tags: c#

I have a service installed as "SYSTEM" that calls a process but I need to run it as a user.

```
try
{
    System.Security.SecureString ssPwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    proc.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.Verb = "runas";
    proc.UserName = "Stevie";
    string p = "Stevie";
    for (int x = 0; x < p.Length; x++)
    {
        ssPwd.AppendChar(p[x]);
    }

    proc.Password = ssPwd;
    proc.FileName = @"C:\DailyTask\GenFile.exe";
    proc.Arguments = "-csv";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
}
catch(Exception errrr)
{
    m.log(errrr.ToString());   
}
```

I used ProcMon to see if it runs under a different user but it won't kick off I get the following error.

```
Sunday, January 24, 2016 --- System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005):Access is denied
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at DirectoryWatcher.MyPOSystemWatcher.Open_f(String filePath)
```

I have complete rights to the directory and its contents.
I have shared it out to "Everyone" and given it read/write access.

Not sure what else I am missing. I am able to manually run the process with out any errors.

Comment: Does your service also have access to `C:\DailyTask\GenFile.exe`? It seems like your exe isn't called in the first place.

Comment: yea it doesn't even start, I have procmon up and have filters set to catch it if it fires but no luck. When you say does my service have access to the file, do you mean the permissions set on that particular .exe ? If so I have it set to all permissions for "Everyone" or do you mean something else?

Comment: Works if I install the service as a "Local Service" as opposed to Local System

Comment: Do you explicitely need Local System privileges?